# export database as different version

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database created in version 5.7.28.  I want to export it as a .sql file and open it on another computer that has MySQL 8.0.19 installed.  What is the right way to export the database so MySQL 8.0.19 can open it?

EDIT

I thought there was a way to "export to version X" from MySQL but I guess there isn't.  I exported from MySQL Workbench version 8.0.18 as a sql file on the computer with MySQL 5.7.28 installed.  On the Mac with Catalina version 10.15.2 I have MySQL version 8.0.19 installed.  In Sequel Pro I made a new, empty database and imported from the .sql file.  It says an unexpected error occurred and gave this:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException

-[_NSInlineData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000332f60

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fa308ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff65ca1805 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2faafb61 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f994adf ___forwarding___ + 1427
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f9944b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Sequel Pro                          0x00000001000587cd -[SPTablesList updateTables:] + 1338
6   Sequel Pro                          0x00000001000493d5 -[SPDataImport importSQLFile:] + 2136
7   Sequel Pro                          0x000000010004f207 -[SPDataImport _importBackgroundProcess:] + 224
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff3204e788 __NSThread__start__ + 1064
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff67213e65 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6720f83b thread_start + 15
)
```

Could someone please help me understand what is going wrong?

Comment: You can only export it in one way and you need to fix any errors as you encounter while you try to import it. There are not that many incompatibilities between the two versions.

Comment: I import the .sql file with Sequel Pro and it totally crashes.

Comment: What does crash? What does crash mean? What is the exact error message? Pls ask a specific question, rather than a vague generic question that one can write a book on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I encountered was due to the software I was using. Sequel Pro is currently on version 1.1.2 that was released in April 2016. It doesn't support MySQL version 8.0.  My log error is identical to ones posted on the GitHub for Sequel Pro.

My solution is to stop using Sequel Pro and switch to MySQL Workbench. I will have to give up the convenient GUI of Sequel Pro and learn more about typing SQL queries by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Be it any version. If you are upgrading then there should not be any problem if you use dump.

```
mysqldump -u user -p databasename > d1.sql
```

and in destination (if mysql)

```
mysql -u user -p databasename < d1.sql
```

destination (other than mysql) too can get the d1.sql inside. There should not be any issues.